# Dependencies in IntelliJ for Android Gradle project

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have gradle project that I compile and install to device using gradle tasks.

I can even debug in IntelliJ.

The problem is that there is no dependency completion for libraries.

Lets take for example robospice.

[Here](http://gyazo.com/e530b7506d1ae01b6fc7617547003610) is what I get inside IntelliJ as dependency for project:

but inside project code I get [this](http://gyazo.com/c6ff32fcc95fa69d84c447421d8f66f6) and [this](http://gyazo.com/3690b112ecfdc51fd1257b1882454998)

Any idea how to set up dependencies correctly?

Comment: Do not post links, post your code here.

Comment: It is more an dependency list and different color of code, and not a code issue itself.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you turn your workflow around. Use the [Gradle IDEA plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html) to generate your IntelliJ project files with modules and stuff configured as per the best likely defaults.

Comment: Otherwise the answer is to File->Invalidate Caches->Restart IDEA which, if you've used IntelliJ for long, you'd have already tried.

Comment: Hello, I used Gradle as an option while I was importing the project to IntelliJ. So I got project structure with 2 modules and main app. But the dependencies are still not correctly fixed. I cannot build the app form intelliJ, while I can build the app using gradle task from terminal. Then I debug with Make deleted from run configuration

Comment: @Tree (it'd help to inline what you've linked as images into your question, you should be allowed to edit your own questions). What you describe isn't the same thing as I recommended and didn't work for me. Check your File->Project Structure that Libraries contains all the "Gradle: com.octo.android..." that you have showing up as a red import. These show up as Java not Maven libraries even though Gradle uses a maven repository. Similarly under Modules I've excluded sources .gradle and build, and Modules' dependencies tab found all the stuff I included in the build.gradle file as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

1) Seems like it's not a a gradle dependencies but maven ones.

2) I suggest you use Android studio instead of InteliJIdea directly.

3) Check if you project is a gradle project but not maven etc.